# How to use Foreach on view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, swiftui

I'm developing my first iOS App,  using Xcode 11.3 and Swift5.

But I was stuck in using ForEach on view.

I want to put certain `struct` in ZStack using Foreach but still get errors.

`Error : Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`

I don't know how to solve this. Can you help me?

```
/* Struct I want to put in */
struct Verses: Identifiable{
    var id: Int
    var verse : Int
}
```

```
/* I want to load all values from struct using foreach in view. */
        ZStack {
            ForEach(controller.verses) { w in              <- Here is where I get error.

                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(28)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                    .offset(x:0, y:68)
                    .frame(width:290, height:280)

                CardView(date: w.date)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ (value) in
......
```

Comment: Could you put Rectangle and CardView into a another view called Cell. Then use Cell in ForEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` row must be represented by *single* View, so you need something like the following (still I'm not sure in type of container, but just for example)

```
ForEach(controller.verses) { w in
  ZStack {
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(28)
        .opacity(0.4)
        .offset(x:0, y:68)
        .frame(width:290, height:280)

    CardView(date: w.date)
    .gesture(DragGesture()
    .onChanged({ (value) in

    ...
  }
}
```